# Why does go v1.8 fail to allocate heap bitmap on armv7 when importing zmq4?

Tags: go, arm

I'm using go v1.8 on an armv7 target and everything works until I import zeromq, and then not even this works:

```
package main

import (
    zmq "github.com/pebbe/zmq4"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
fmt.Println(zmq.Version())
}
```

Running it on the target gives the following:

```
./zmq 
fatal error: runtime: out of memory

runtime stack:
runtime.throw(0xc8d3d, 0x16)
        /usr/lib/go/src/runtime/panic.go:596 +0x70 fp=0x7eb018a0 sp=0x7eb01894
runtime.sysMap(0x6d752000, 0x74d4000, 0x1, 0x146b60)
        /usr/lib/go/src/runtime/mem_linux.go:227 +0xb0 fp=0x7eb018c4 sp=0x7eb018a0
runtime.(*mheap).mapBits(0x139d58, 0x74d26000)
        /usr/lib/go/src/runtime/mbitmap.go:159 +0x94 fp=0x7eb018dc sp=0x7eb018c4
runtime.(*mheap).sysAlloc(0x139d58, 0x100000, 0x30414)
        /usr/lib/go/src/runtime/malloc.go:428 +0x2dc fp=0x7eb0191c sp=0x7eb018dc
runtime.(*mheap).grow(0x139d58, 0x8, 0x0)
        /usr/lib/go/src/runtime/mheap.go:774 +0xd0 fp=0x7eb0194c sp=0x7eb0191c
runtime.(*mheap).allocSpanLocked(0x139d58, 0x1, 0x0)
        /usr/lib/go/src/runtime/mheap.go:678 +0x468 fp=0x7eb0196c sp=0x7eb0194c
runtime.(*mheap).alloc_m(0x139d58, 0x1, 0x10, 0x0, 0x0)
        /usr/lib/go/src/runtime/mheap.go:562 +0xdc fp=0x7eb019a4 sp=0x7eb0196c
runtime.(*mheap).alloc.func1()
        /usr/lib/go/src/runtime/mheap.go:627 +0x3c fp=0x7eb019c0 sp=0x7eb019a4
runtime.systemstack(0x7eb019d4)
        /usr/lib/go/src/runtime/asm_arm.s:278 +0xa8 fp=0x7eb019c4 sp=0x7eb019c0
runtime.(*mheap).alloc(0x139d58, 0x1, 0x10, 0x100, 0x1)
        /usr/lib/go/src/runtime/mheap.go:628 +0x60 fp=0x7eb019ec sp=0x7eb019c4
runtime.(*mcentral).grow(0x13ab98, 0x0)
        /usr/lib/go/src/runtime/mcentral.go:212 +0x84 fp=0x7eb01a18 sp=0x7eb019ec
runtime.(*mcentral).cacheSpan(0x13ab98, 0x146b68)
        /usr/lib/go/src/runtime/mcentral.go:93 +0x104 fp=0x7eb01a5c sp=0x7eb01a18
runtime.(*mcache).refill(0x649e5000, 0x10, 0x146b68)
        /usr/lib/go/src/runtime/mcache.go:122 +0x7c fp=0x7eb01a70 sp=0x7eb01a5c
runtime.(*mcache).nextFree.func1()
        /usr/lib/go/src/runtime/malloc.go:525 +0x24 fp=0x7eb01a80 sp=0x7eb01a70
runtime.systemstack(0x7eb01aa4)
        /usr/lib/go/src/runtime/asm_arm.s:278 +0xa8 fp=0x7eb01a84 sp=0x7eb01a80
runtime.(*mcache).nextFree(0x649e5000, 0x649e5010, 0x7eb01acc, 0x1ebd4, 0x21c40)
        /usr/lib/go/src/runtime/malloc.go:526 +0x9c fp=0x7eb01ab0 sp=0x7eb01a84
runtime.mallocgc(0xf0, 0xc2548, 0x1, 0x64a26001)
        /usr/lib/go/src/runtime/malloc.go:678 +0x8c0 fp=0x7eb01b08 sp=0x7eb01ab0
runtime.newobject(0xc2548, 0x1384a0)
        /usr/lib/go/src/runtime/malloc.go:807 +0x2c fp=0x7eb01b1c sp=0x7eb01b08
runtime.malg(0x8000, 0x2710)
        /usr/lib/go/src/runtime/proc.go:2821 +0x1c fp=0x7eb01b38 sp=0x7eb01b1c
runtime.mpreinit(0x138730)
        /usr/lib/go/src/runtime/os_linux.go:302 +0x1c fp=0x7eb01b44 sp=0x7eb01b38
runtime.mcommoninit(0x138730)
        /usr/lib/go/src/runtime/proc.go:540 +0x94 fp=0x7eb01b5c sp=0x7eb01b44
runtime.schedinit()
        /usr/lib/go/src/runtime/proc.go:476 +0x40 fp=0x7eb01b78 sp=0x7eb01b5c
runtime.rt0_go(0x7eb01d14, 0x76ee4000, 0x7eb01d14, 0x1, 0x5cd10, 0x7eb01c58, 0x76f8e000, 0xcef6f281, 0xc6a63e08, 0x128, ...)
        /usr/lib/go/src/runtime/asm_arm.s:61 +0x84 fp=0x7eb01bb8 sp=0x7eb01b78
```

Tracing shows the offending mmap:

```
mmap2(0x74c54000, 1048576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x74c54000
mmap2(0x6d77e000, 122511360, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = -1 ENOMEM (Cannot allocate memory)
```

The first one is right, that's the chunk size, but the second is where it allocates the bitmap. It should be probably 16x smaller.

I tried debugging but it works under GDB. Maybe GDB does some virtualization?

```
gdbserver :1000 zmq
Process zmq created; pid = 817
Listening on port 1000
Remote debugging from host 10.0.0.36
4 2 1

Child exited with status 0
```

So far, all pure go programs I've tested work as well.

Why does importing zeromq cause it to fail? Is there a bug in the arm port of go?

Comment: This definitely belongs on the [golang issue tracker](https://github.com/golang/go/issues).

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll copy it there.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed by https://github.com/golang/go/commit/bb6309cd63b35a81a8527efaad58847a83039947

libzmq must contain some global constructors which adjust the process memory map before the go runtime starts.